# Are apt-file and apt-cache part of apt?

Tags: apt, package-management, apt-file

Is `apt-file` part of `apt`? I have `apt` installed by default, but no `apt-file`.

How about `apt-cache`? I don't remember whether mine was installed by default or me.

Comment: @muru: How ironic that one of those methods involves `apt-file`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`apt-file` is its own separate program that is not part of `apt`, but has interactions with `apt` components, more specifically it pulls a list of 'files' known in packages and then searches the data in those lists of files to find certain searched-for terms and parameters.  It has `apt`-like functions but it's its own package in the Universe (non-main, community-contributed and supported) repositories.

`apt-cache` however *is* part of the `apt` packages/suite, and is a 'standard' `apt` utility/program that is installed with every Ubuntu installation.

Comment: Interesting tid-bit `sudo apt install apt` reveals: `apt is already the newest version (1.2.24).`

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix um, why would it *not* say that?

Comment: Because it leads one to think about `sudo apt remove apt`, `sudo apt remove dkpg` and then `sudo apt-get remove apt-get` (this last one I'm not sure about).

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix they both complain if you try and remove themselves, in a typical installation

Comment: I'm not brave enough to try it :D Just thought it was interesting thought experiment :)

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix if you remove the apt package, you will not be able to use apt to remove dpkg. apt-get is a binary, not a package.

Comment: @Braiam Yes I noticed the binary component when I tried `apt list apt-get`. I guess you would have to `sudo apt remove dpkg` before `sudo apt remove apt`. Again just a thought experiment, nothing important....